# Adding BeautifulSoup find element in a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, append, typeerror

I have the following code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.seminuevos.com/usados/-/autos/-/volkswagen")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

kkt = soup.find_all("div", class_="card hoverable") # mazga
for tag in kkt:
    print(tag.find('a', href=True)['href'])
```

With this code i am getting the links that i want(printed only), but i cannot append them to a list.
If i use :

```
list = []
for tag in kkt:
    item = tag.find('a', href=True)['href']
    list.append(item)
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How can i append the result of : for tag in kkt: item = tag.find('a', href=True)['href'] to a list, line by line ?
I`ve also tried :

```
list = [tag.find('a', href=True)['href'] for tag in kkt]
```

Not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because not all `div` tags in the `kkt` iterable contain `a` tags, so the `find` in the loop is sometimes returning `None`. Change it to look like so:

```
for tag in kkt:
    item = tag.find('a', href=True)
    if item:
        list.append(item['href'])
```